# Как осуществить побитовое чтение и запись в Java

Tags: java

Приветствую!

Реализую на java "жадное" кодирование. А именно [Код Шеннона](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%CA%EE%E4_%D8%E5%ED%ED%EE%ED%E0).

Есть ли возможность записывать в файл и читать из файла набор бит не кратный 8? (желательно без изобретения велосипедов)

У меня была мысль воспользоваться классом BitSet. Создать bitSet для каждой кодовой последовательности, а потом при чтении файла производить конкатенацию нужных bitSet-ов. Полученный большой bitSet конвертировать в массив байт и записывать его в файл. Но есть несколько НО!

1. bitset.length() возвращает индекс старшего установленного в 1 бита. Так как кодовая последовательность заканчивается битами установленными в 0, приходится хранить длину кодовой последовательность отдельно.
2. метод toByteArray() "переворачивает" биты. Если в bitSet-е установлены {0, 1, 2, 4} биты, то байт выглядит как 10111
3. реализация конкатенации тоже остаётся за мной, хоть это не страшно.

Декодирование сейчас представляю только как чтение одного или нескольких байт и получение бит с помощью сдвигов.

Может есть более элегантное решение этой задачи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для своих целей всё-таки пришлось реализовать класс-обёртку для существующего класса BitSet. Так же хочется отметить, что методы `.length()` и `.toByteArray()` (а так же противоположный метод для конвертации ByteArray в BitSet) работают вполне адекватно. Самый младший бит, которому BitSet присваивает индекс 0, соответствует самому младшему биту в байте, который является "самым правым". Это уже мне понадобилось отойти от стандартной записи.

А вот и тот самый класс:

```
public class MyBitSet {

    public MyBitSet(BitSet bs, int length) {
        bitset = bs;
        this.bitLength = length;
    }
    BitSet bitset;

    private int bitLength; // количество полезных бит
    private int bitcount; // счётчик бит для временного байта. Используется для сдвига
    private int tmpByte; // буфферный байт
    private ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
    private ByteArrayInputStream bais;

    public long getBitLength() {
        return this.bitLength;
    }

    public MyBitSet getSubBitSet(int start, int end) {
        MyBitSet mbs = new MyBitSet(end - start);
        for(int i = start, j = 0; i < end; i++) {
            mbs.bitset.set(j, this.bitset.get(i));
        }
        return mbs;
    }

    public MyBitSet(String filename) {
        bais = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            File f = new File(filename);
            fis = new FileInputStream(f);

            byte[] byteFile;
            byteFile = new byte[(int) f.length()];
            fis.read(byteFile, 0, (int) f.length());
            this.bitset = new BitSet((int) f.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < byteFile.length; i++) {
                byte b = byteFile[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    bitset.set(i*8 + j, getBit(b, 7 - j));
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyBitSet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyBitSet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if(fis != null){
                try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MyBitSet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.bitset.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof MyBitSet)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        MyBitSet set = (MyBitSet) obj;

        if (this.bitset.equals(set.bitset) && this.bitLength == set.bitLength) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void concatenate(BitSet bs, int length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++, bitLength++, bitcount--) {
            int myInt = (bs.get(i)) ? 1 : 0; // true = 1, false = 0
            tmpByte |= (myInt << (bitcount));

            if (bitcount == 0) {
                bitcount = 8;
                baos.write(tmpByte);
                tmpByte = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    void writeToFile(String filename) {
        if (bitcount != 7) {
            baos.write(tmpByte);//добавить последние биты, оставшиеся во временном байте
        }
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            baos.writeTo(outputStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyBitSet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyBitSet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MyBitSet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    byte[] getByteArray() {
        if (bitcount != 7) {
            baos.write(tmpByte);//добавить последние биты, оставшиеся во временном байте
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }

    public MyBitSet() {
        bitLength = 0;
        bitcount = 7;
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    }

    public MyBitSet(int bitSetLength) {
        this.bitset = new BitSet(bitSetLength);
        this.bitLength = bitSetLength;
    }

    private static boolean getBit(byte b, int i) {
        return ((b >> i) & 1) == 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Касательно

```
Есть ли возможность записывать в файл и читать из файла набор бит не кратный 8?
```

Нет, нельзя. На самом деле ты даже не сможешь прочитать из файла количество байт не кратное 512. Так как это стандартный размер сектора на жестком диске (сейчас все переходят на 4096). ОС просто скрывает операции вырезки конкретного куска байт, после чтения из файла, от разработчика и буферезирует чтение из файла.

```
   bitset.length() возвращает индекс старшего установленного в 1 бита. Так как кодовая последовательность заканчивается битами установленными в 0, приходится хранить длину кодовой последовательность отдельно.
```

Используй метод [size()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#size%28%29)

```
метод toByteArray() "переворачивает" биты. Если в bitSet-е установлены {0, 1, 2, 4} биты, то байт выглядит как 10111
```

Если у тебя изначально есть словарик BitSet'ов, то ты можешь подогнать их согласно нужному тебе порядку

Comment: Да. С побитовой записью я погорячился. На самом деле мне не так важно, сколько байт и бит я запишу. Интереснее было бы абстрагироваться от чтения нужного количества байт и выделения из них необходимого количества бит. Но, судя по всему, ничего такого в стандартных библиотеках нет.

Comment: `BitSet bs = new BitSet(3);
 System.out.println(bs.size()); // 64`

size() тоже не подходит

Comment: В стандартных коллекция ты ничего такого не найдешь, ибо даже уже BitSet не рекомендуется к использованию. Без извращений тут никак. Попробуй List<Boolean>, если не сильно интересуют вопросы производительности. Там есть методы для всего, что тебе требуется: выделение нужного количества "бит", размер массива "бит".

Answer (score 0):

у меня есть очень небольшая библиотечка для таких целей называется [JBBP](https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser) которая поддерживает битовую запись и чтение, можно воспользоваться её классами [JBBPBitInputStream](https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser/blob/master/src/main/java/com/igormaznitsa/jbbp/io/JBBPBitInputStream.java) и [JBBPBitOutputStream](https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser/blob/master/src/main/java/com/igormaznitsa/jbbp/io/JBBPBitOutputStream.java)